# convert hex string (python 2) to byte with hex numbers in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, type-conversion, hex, byte

I'm converting my code so it works with Python 3. The main remaining issue is to successfully use a serial.write command. In my previous code I made a string like this:
read_frame='\xAA\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x65\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x6F\x71'. And then used serial.write(read_frame) to send this string.

In Python 3, however, I have to convert this to a 'byte' in order to be able to use serial.write(read_frame). If it was a static frame it is sufficient to declare it as:
read_frame_byte=b'\xAA\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x65\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x6F\x71'

The problem, is however, that I create this hex string dynamically, so in the end I have to convert the string to byte. If i'm using the command read_frame.encode('utf-8'), the conversion results in different hex number (x65 becomes xe, for example, as this is the corresponding ASCII value). This is technically correct, but I just want to convert the string to a byte without changing any values. Any suggestions/workarounds to make this conversion?

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow.

It would be useful for others to see a more complete example of your non working code to give better context

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are creating a hex string of the form `"AA0001000000650000000A006F71"` and you want to create a byte from each pair of hex digits. I shouldn't have to guess ...

Take your data:

```
>>> digits = "AA0001000000650000000A006F71"
```

Split it into two-character chunks:

```
>>> [digits[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(digits), 2)]
['AA', '00', '01', '00', '00', '00', '65', '00', '00', '00', '0A', '00', '6F', '71']
```

Add conversion to integer, telling the `int` built-in to use base 16:

```
>>> [int(digits[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(digits), 2)]
[170, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 101, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 111, 113]
```

Finally, convert the list of integers to a `bytes` object:

```
>>> bytes([int(digits[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(digits), 2)])
b'\xaa\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00\n\x00oq'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. My apologies if my question was not clear enough.
Now the problem, however,is that the resulting byte b'\xaa\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00\n\x00oq', is not equal to the result I want, namely:
b'\xAA\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x65\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x6F\x71'. Is there a way to retrieve that exact result with your method?

Comment: I think you will find if you check that the hex code for "o" is 6F. Python doesn't use escape codes to represent printable ASCII characters!

Comment: thanks, it works now, finally. The problem was that with my previous conversion method, namely:
bytes(read_frame.encode()), the resulting byte starts with an extra character 'xc2': 
b'\xc2\xaa\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00\n\x00oq'. Therefore I thought the whole frame was not in the right format. Apparently this extra byte  was the reason the communication did not work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, and don't worry about the non-obvious question: my psychic powers apparently still work! Next time, ask yourself if *you* woud understand the question if you were someone else ;-)